# Do text connections always have to be closed?

Tags: r

`textConnection`s are usually created as below:

```
> temp <- c("samplea sampleb samplec")
> tc <- textConnection(temp)
> read.delim(tc,header=F,sep="")
       V1      V2      V3
1 samplea sampleb samplec
> close(tc)
```

But, if I don't create a text connection object like below:

```
> temp <- c("samplea sampleb samplec")
> read.delim(textConnection(temp),header=F,sep="")
       V1      V2      V3
1 samplea sampleb samplec
```

How do I close the connection? And what happens if I don't close it?

Comment: If you don't close it, it will remain open.  There is a limit to how many connections you can have open at one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a textConnection for this. You can just do

```
read.delim(text="samplea sampleb samplec", header=F, sep=" ")
```

If you still want to use a text, connection, just make it a proper object and close it when you are done

```
temp <- c("samplea sampleb samplec")
tc <- textConnection(temp)
read.delim(tc, header=F, sep="")
close(tc)
```

If you don't close it, you will see it listed in

```
showConnections()
```

You can close connections from that table using the row number. For example

```
close(getConnection(1))
```

or you can close all connections with

```
closeAllConnections()
```